Carbon Copy Cloner folder backup versioning
Macos Sonoma v14.6.1
Carbon Copy Cloner v7.0.4
My pwSafe vault is stored on iCloud drive which enables access from my ios devices.  Sweet.
I'm aware iCloud drive is backed-up, but that only gives me access to the most recent backup of the vault.
I have CCC configured to backup the pwSafe iCloud folder, but that also only gives me the most recent backup version of the vault.
Can I configure CCC to provide historical backup versions of my pwSafe iCloud folder in a similar manner to how it makes volume backup snapshots?

The trick is make sure that the destination is an APFS volume.
On your backup disk, create an APFS volume to be used as the destination of your CCC task.
Create the CCC task with source your home folder and destination the new APFS volume. Use the Task Filter to select what you want to be backed up. My cloud backup task does a backup of all iCloud Drive and all of File Provider cloud storage (e.g. Dropbox).  Here is my task:

Note that I have enabled "Temporarily download cloud-only files to make a local backup" in case some of the files are cloud only.
In the Task Filter make this a "Define what is included" task - click "Include" at top right. Select what you want backed up. I choose all of ~/Library/Cloud Storage and ~/Library/Mobile Documents, but you can restrict it to just a single folder in Mobile Documents.
Looking inside CCC's Task Filter, ~/Library/Mobile Documents includes both iCloud folders (mostly created by apps) and any explicitly created iCloud Drive folders.  The iCloud Drive content is in ~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud Drive.
Inspect the new volume. Here is mine after many backups:

Make sure you enable "CCC Snapshots" and choose snapshot thinning to meet what you would like.  Mine is somewhat like Time Machine.
Now you will get a new snapshot for every backup.  Use the right-click (Control-click) menu to view particular snapshots in Finder.

thank you, gilby.  i’m currently traveling. i’ll implement your suggestion in a week and see how it goes.

CCC v7.0.4   I created an encrypted APFS volume.  I selected Cloud Storage as the source. I selected the APFS volume as the destination.  In Task Filter I can select Documents, but I have folders in the root of my iCloud Drive.  I don't see how to include those.  The task runs successfully.

~/Library/Mobile Documents is where your iCloud and iCloud Drive is stored. Your added folders in iCloud Drive are in ~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud Drive (as presented by CCC). I will add a bit re this to the answer.

Gilby, sorry to be a tad dense about this, but I do not have a folder ~/Library/Mobile Documents.   And yes I've enabled display of hidden folders in Finder.  Sonoma v14.6.1

Finder hides ~/Library/Mobile Documents. CCC shows it in the Task Filter.

I have slected "Cloud Storage" as my source in my task.  The Task Filter shows the Documents folder, but not Mobile Documents.  I've also tried selecting my user folder as Source, with the same result.  So, I've moved all my root iCloud content under Documents and selected it in the filter.  This suffices.  Thanks again.

I've checked your answer since you have been so helpful and I have a backup solution.
